# htaccess rewrite rule 3 variables

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteRule ^albums/([^/.]*)/?$ albums.php?user=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^albums/([^/.]*)/([^/.]*)/?$ albums.php?user=$1&name=$2&album_id=$3 [L,QSA]

original
albums.php?user=123&name=foo&album_id=456

result
albums/123/foo/456
```

I have a htaccess rewrite url, I need to set up 3 get variables, but this code is not working

anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is wrong. You can use:

```
#For 3 variables:
RewriteRule ^albums/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ albums.php?user=$1&name=$2&album_id=$3 [L,QSA]

# for 2 variables:
RewriteRule ^albums/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ albums.php?user=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: what if this page can be 2 & 3 variables both?

Comment: There are 2 rules now one for 3 and one for 2 variables.